# Printing specific number from a different file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem in my code. I have two files that has to work together, in one of the files I have this code

```
def __getitem__(self, gf): 
      
        file=self.filename
        for i in file:
            self.sequence_list.append(float(i))
        if gf<= len(self.sequence_list):
            return self.sequence_list
        else:
            gf>len(self.sequence_list)
            print("There's only " + str(len(self.sequence_list)) + "quotas.")
            raise IndexError
```

And then I have the other file with this code

```
filename = it.input_type(str, "filename = ")
  gf = myseq.MultiplicativeSequenceFromFile(filename)
  print(f"gf[12] = {gf[12]}")
```

I'm trying to print out the 12th element of the sequence.csv file I'm importing which contains these numbers:

```
1.01
1.02
1.05
1.01
1.03
1.01
1.02
1.05
1.01
1.03
1.01
1.02
1.05
1.01
1.03
```

However it's printing out every number in the file and I don't understand why it's not printing out the 12th. I'm trying to make into a generic code but I can't make it print out the 12th number.

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete but minimal code, example input, and expected output. You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Sidenote: `f"gf[12] = {gf[12]}"` can be simplified to `f"{gf[12] = }"`

Comment: Oh wait, `return self.sequence_list`? That should be `return self.sequence_list[gf]`. In the future, making a [mre] will help catch simple typos like that.

Comment: BTW, `gf>len(self.sequence_list)` is dangling. You might have meant it as an `elif`, but it's already implied by being in the `else` of `gf <= len(self.sequence_list)`.

Comment: @wjandrea changing to return self.sequence_list[gf] solved the problem thank you!

Comment: @wjandrea how would you solve the situation with the `gf>len(self.sequence_list)` I don't understand how I should make the code read it since it says the print expression even though gf is 12

Comment: By "dangling" I mean it's being evaluated, but it doesn't actually do anything. You can simply remove it. Like I said, it's redundant anyway.

Comment: @wjandrea I underand but in this context I need to have some error handling in case the user writes in 18 and there's only 15 numbers in the list, if I remove this then no error will arise which is necessary

Comment: *"if I remove this then no error will arise"* -- Are you sure about that? Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @wjandrea oh hahaha i'm sorry thank you!